# Changing DNS providers with glue records currently on domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, glue-record

Our company is currently looking to migrate our DNS provider away from where it currently is, over to Zerigo. My only concern before 'flicking the switch' is that we currently have vanity nameservers, and glue records - a feature that we won't be bothering with after the migration.

Our current setup is like this:

```
Domain Name:                     company.com.au

Name Server:                     ns1.company.com.au
Name Server IP:                  123.45.7.89
Name Server:                     ns2.company.com.au
Name Server IP:                  123.45.7.90
```

With the following glue records:

```
123.45.7.89 [US] (ns1.company.com.au)
123.45.7.90 [US] (ns2.company.com.au)
```

My question is: **If I do this migration without removing the glue records, will I break something?** If so, how should I be tackling this migration.

**Edit from the discussion below:**

The reason why I am asking is because our registrar are pretty painful to deal with over the phone, and that's the only way we can change the glue records - however I am able to change the NS records using their web-based tools. Just trying to see if I can avoid having to make that call, at least in the short term :)

Comment: Down votes? I honestly don't know where I went wrong with this question - anyone care to shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously need to change the NS records with the registrar in order to change your DNS provider. Leaving the glue records in place should technically work (clients will just ignore them since they don't match the nameservers they're trying to find), but since you're changing records at the registrar you might as well remove them. The registrar may not allow non-matching glue records anyway.

Comment: I guess I should've specified that I have to _phone_ my registrar to change the glue records (painful), but I can update the NS records through their website. Hoping to avoid having to do anything over the phone with them :)

Comment: @theTRON That would make the question a bit more sensible. You should be able to change the NS records without changing the glue records.

Comment: Somethings in life really suck, but we still have to do them... +1